# Deploying WSO2 ESB 4.6.0 onto JBoss 7

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm looking for a way to deploy `WSO2 ESB` onto `JBoss 7`. I saw in the Web such manuals for `JBoss 5.1.0`. AFAIK `JBoss 7` is quite different from `JBoss 5.1.0`. In particular, forked from Tomcat JBossWeb is used there instead of Tomcat. Therefore I don't think that a manual for `JBoss 5.1.0` is suitable for `JBoss 7`. Has somebody done the subj successfully? Is there any manual, guide or something like that, describing how to do this?

Comment: WSO2 ESB is a complete product , it is not a integration framework like Apache Camel or Spring Integration. WS02ESB has all the features security,transaction inorder to be a standone container. I would never deploy a WSO2 ESB in a App Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We stopped supporting webarchive deployment model from carbon 4.0.0 and later versions. So, you can not deploy the esb4.6.0 inside jboss.

Answer (score 2):

In fact you can't gain real performance level provide by WSO2 ESB when deploying it on a manged environment like Application server instead you should allow ESB to mange its low level resource itself. Any way what is your use case here to deploy WSO2 ESB on JBoss Application server ?

Comment: There is an application using JBoss 7 as an application server. I'm going to use WSO2 ESB as a service bus for this application. AFAIK WSO2 ESB is a Tomcat based application. Since JBoss has a Tomcat/JBossWeb inside I didn't see any reason to have two Tomcat instances on one server. Lower performance and impossibility to deploy WSO2 ESB inside JBoss are good reasons to deploy it standalone :)

Comment: First of all your comment is based on incorrect details, WSO2 ESB is does not based on Tomcat or it didn't build top of Tomcat, instead WSO2 ESB is based on Apache Synpase and build top of WSO2 Carbon OSGI platform. In fact WSO2 Application server is the Apache Tomcat based product. For more details about ESB architecture please refer following blog http://techfeast-hiranya.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-worlds-fastest-esb-was-made.html

Comment: About performance you haven't mention any source where you find such claim but it can be your personal opinion. I'm not claim  bout WSO2  ESB performance here instead you could run bench mark test suite provided here http://wso2.org/library/articles/2013/01/esb-performance-65 with WSO2 ESB and any other ESB to find truth yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the info about WSO2 ESB architecture. The `ESB_HOME/lib/tomcat` directory confused me. Therefore I thought that WSO2 ESB uses Tomcat as a container.  
My opinion about performance is based on your answer in this topic. If I understand you correctly, WSO2 ESB has better performance when deployed separately, not on any kind of application server. If so, I'd rather deploy WSO2 ESB separately. That's what I meant in my previous comment. I didn't mean that WSO2 ESB has low performance. Sorry if my previous comment was ambiguous.