# Can API manager 2.1.0 deploy on jboss

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

Can any one tell if API manager can  deploy on jboss ?

Also can anyone tell how to maintain directory sync between 2 manager nodes ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

API manager does not require any application server to run. Depsync between two manager nodes is possible via svn based dep-sync. Details to configure the depsync are available [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+SVN-Based+Deployment+Synchronizer).

> When working with two manager nodes In a scenario where there are two
>   manager nodes, if both servers start with the same default files in
>   /repository/deployment/server an error occurs. The
>   second management node should not have these default files within its
>   /repository/deployment/server location. To avoid
>   conflicts with regards to commits from the second node, the second
>   node should not have the set of files that the first node has
>   committed when the second node connects to the cluster.

Comment: Hi anuruddha thanks for the reply I understand stand that we don't need a app server but I was asking does it support the deployment in jboss?

Comment: Second can we achieve the directory sync using rsync between 2 manager nodes because I don't have svn present in the server setup.If I keep two manager nodes what will be gateway URL of two because in active passive deployment documentation it is told to point to only one gateway

Answer (score 0):

According to this article Yes, we can deploy.
 Just follow the steps mentioned in the [article](http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/2011/03/running-wso2-carbon310-based-products-jboss-5x/) ant varify this.

You can follow the below steps to [configure rsync](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+rsync+for+Deployment+Synchronization)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785764/deploying-wso2-esb-4-6-0-onto-jboss-7 in this link it's mentioned that wso2 4.0+ carbon products can't be deployed on jboss and regarding rsync in the link it's mentioned that we can have one manager only but I need to maintain two manager nodes